# Automapper using Interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

```
interface Parent
{
     string A;
     string C;
}
class ChildA : Parent
{
     string A;
     string C;
}
class ChildB : Parent
{
     string A;
     string C;
}

class RelatedC
{
     string A;
     string B;
}
//On app start
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent,RelatedC>();
//Map member A only 

//In some other class
var rel // RelatedC type object, not null has data
var obj// ChildA type object, not null has data
//I want to use the above map created to map rel and obj
Mapper.Map(rel ,obj )
//only property A will be overridden by rel, other properties for obj are not changed
```

I want to use the mapper of interface for all the classes which will use the interface, I dont want to create individual maps for each child class.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can't you just do `var obj = Mapper.Map<Parent>(rel)` ? I don't think you need to configure the mapping for each `Parent` implementor.

Comment: @Jasen No i cannot do that because obj as being used in the project is not implemented using  new, it has properties and using var obj = Mapper.Map<Parent>(rel) will basically make a new object. So rel will override some properties of obj (the ones which will be mapped)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DynamicMap`:

```
Mapper.DynamicMap(relatedC, childA);
```

This will map `A` and keep the value of `C`. It doesn't create a new instance and the values are mapped directly to the destination type's object (in this case, `childA`).

**Edit:** It obviously only works if you register the mapping first:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RelatedC, Parent>();
```

Comment: I have already tried it, and obviously that doesn't work. It will not be able to map as it gives error since there is no map for class but for the interface, which is the original problem.

Comment: You should check your code then. It works as expected. For instance, your `Parent` interface won't even compile as provided in the question.